# putty and remina work but telnet and ssh do not

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, telnet, bashrc

I am connecting from a ubuntu 20.04 to a raspberry pi 4 B also on Ubuntu 20.04
telnet dies immediately
ssh can be forced with ssh -T user@host
however there is no prompt,
the prompt can be restored by typing bash -i but then I get snot about no pty / tty and searching for hours on how to restore the tty or pty revealed that this is a common problem without a common solution.  also the arrows do not work and while it is possible to execute commands it is not friendly.
putty works as you would expect a terminal session to work, arrows and copy and paste,
remina also works as expected.

I am asking this question as a pass, I am ok with using remina and not telnet or ssh.

I have tried many things including adding networks to /etc/hosts.allow and most all of the solutions found in many sites with similar errors.  most people have these errors when they try to run scripts as other users, I am not doing that.  I have root access to both of the machines and they are both inside my firewall.
my favorite error is:
bash: cannot set terminal process group (4978): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
this led to hours of trying to add job control to a shell, :(
and learning all about process groups
this one is good also
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input
so basically ssh and telnet do not create a proper terminal.  How? why?  please help....;)

result of `ssh -vvv user@host`:

```
buntu@ubuntu:~$ ssh -vv marc@192.168.1.241
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.241 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.241 [192.168.1.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.241:22 as 'marc'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:AR3puAqOfjZkJiwFOZEtYNcJPBnPcDRtUZhP08OrSz4
debug1: Host '192.168.1.241' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5QNcvcNfqDsoKEAmvzH0FPbFwHcNag9f1IFNLjDjc5w
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5QNcvcNfqDsoKEAmvzH0FPbFwHcNag9f1IFNLjDjc5w
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
marc@192.168.1.241's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.241 ([192.168.1.241]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1019-raspi aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon Sep 28 14:17:45 CDT 2020

  System load:           0.0
  Usage of /:            5.7% of 58.27GB
  Memory usage:          8%
  Swap usage:            0%
  Temperature:           34.6 C
  Processes:             177
  Users logged in:       2
  IPv4 address for eth0: 192.168.1.241
  IPv6 address for eth0: 2600:1700:30c1:7cd0::14
  IPv6 address for eth0: 2600:1700:30c1:7cd0:dea6:32ff:fe5b:e91b

 * Kubernetes 1.19 is out! Get it in one command with:

     sudo snap install microk8s --channel=1.19 --classic

   https://microk8s.io/ has docs and details.

0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.


Last login: Mon Sep 28 14:05:09 2020 from 192.168.1.241
```

Comment: `Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1019-raspi aarch64)` – IMO this means the `ssh` (without `-T`) *works*. What is wrong then? Why do you think you need `-T`? Is there no prompt? I know you said there's no prompt after `ssh -T` but now I'm trying to help you with the case where `-T` is not used. It's not clear why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: after the ssh prints its nice welcome screen I do not have an ssh session I have a prompt on my machine, not the host. it does not even have the courtesy to say my session was closed just flows right back to my machine.

Comment: Please do not kill me,  ssh is now working, and I think it was because I did an ssh-keygen and added the keys to my home/.ssh directory.

Comment: We're cool. Based on the information you provided I cannot explain what happened though. If the problem is no more, consider deleting the question. Or if you want someone to explain what happened, let the question be. But then the question should be rebuilt to contain all the relevant information, to describe the past and the actual situation, to include the exact command(s) that apparently helped. So your latest comments (and more) should be there. Make sure you ask a well defined question (e.g. "What was wrong exactly and why did the command(s) help?").